# Saving file from the gallery to the app external storage

Tags: android, file, copy

In my app the user can select a picture from their gallery as avatar, but i want to save it into my app storage so they can delete the file.

My code is:

```
//onActivityResult()
else if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE)
            {
                mFile = new File(getRealPathFromURI(data.getData()));

                Date d = new Date();
                long ms = d.getTime();
                mName = String.valueOf(ms) + ".jpg";

                copyfile(mFile,mName);

                File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), mName);
                Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
                imgPhoto.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

            }

   public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri)
{
    // can post image
    String [] proj={MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery( contentUri,proj,null,null,null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
} 


    private void copyfile(File file,String newFileName){
    try{
      InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
      OutputStream out = openFileOutput(newFileName, MODE_PRIVATE);
      byte[] buf = new byte[4096];
      int len;
      while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0){
        out.write(buf, 0, len);
      }
      in.close();
      out.close();
      Log.d(null,"success");
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();     
    }
  }
```

If i decode mFile in the Bitmap, the image is shown, so mFile has the image. ¿Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Well, first of all... you haven't told us the behavior you are currently getting. Does your app crash? Does the picture not get displayed? Some other unexpected behavior?

Other than that:

1. Don't use `managedQuery()`... it's run on the main UI thread so it can easily introduce lag into your application. Ideally you'd want to use a `CursorLoader` but it might be easier to just wrap all of your work in an `AsyncTask` (by "all of your work" I mean all of the work related to saving/retrieving/decoding the image file... and I suggest this because it can take a considerable amount of time to do all of this stuff, and your app might look slow if the UI thread is blocked for too long).
2. If you do choose to wrap your work in an `AsyncTask` (which I suggest you do), put all of the work in `doInBackground()` and update your UI accordingly when you are finished in `onPostExecute()`.

Comment: Thanks for the tips!!

When I set the imagebitmap on the ImageView, the imageView looks transparent, so I guess that there's no data to load.

If i load the mFile into the bitmap, the image appears, so I think that the image retrieval is ok.